# Remix IDE does not show the deployed functions under the deployed contracts option

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am compiling solidity code using REMIX IDE, however, when I deploy my code, it does not show the functions under the deployed contracts menu. Please guide, I think there is some problem in my browser as the same code runs fine on another friend's computer.

My code should also show the functions with input values, however, it only shows the following screen.
[image]
[![][2]][2]

The actuall functions with input values are shown below.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhhlQ.png

Comment: Which Browser are you using? and can you  please share your code? Most of the times such things in Remix happens due to browser. So it is always better for you to develop using framework locally.

Comment: I am using chrome browser, I am also of the opinion this is happening due to the browser, but I wanted to have a second opinion. Could you guide me on which local framework would be best? P.S. I am new to solidity programming.

Comment: Yes, most probably it is happening due to chrome. You can try 'Truffle' for your development.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you experience these kind of behaviour due to browser. Change your browser and it will work fine or you can try developing your smart contract with e.g. Truffle.

https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/overview

Comment: I tried changing browsers, as well as switching to mac with different browsers from a windows machine, however was not able to find any solution.

Comment: Please share your code, i will be only able to help then.