# Remix IDE - Issue with functions when deploying smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I was trying to deploy the following smart contract on Remix IDE:
[Remix deployment, can't share as an image yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWz0D.jpg)

As you may see, Remix doesn't let me work on the deployed functions. The only thing I can do is interacting via calldata. I checked on other links like this one: [Remix IDE does not show the deployed functions under the deployed contracts option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468310/remix-ide-does-not-show-the-deployed-functions-under-the-deployed-contracts-opti) but there's no issue regarding the web browser. I've already deployed it using Chrome and Brave, but didn't work. Can anyone give me a hint on this? I'd really appreciate it.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are making every function and variables as `internal`. Internal functions are limited to the contract level and thats why you dont see them after deployment. Replace `internal` with `external` on the functions you want to call after deployment.

Comment: Thx very much Taimoor!! That was it.

Comment: Or he can replace `internal` with `public`!